# Why was the user Summon ousted from SF?

Tags: support, moderation, abuse, account-suspension, spam

Why was the user Summon ousted from SF?

His correct reply to his own question

- [Windows Server 2008 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1/)

was deleted and the question distorted through editing

If community doesn't like my replies, there is no reason to repel the newbie whom I responded.

BTW, what is exactly the reason that I was suspended?

---

**vgv8** (participant with over 100 posts and an average of 450% of downvotes)

Probably I shall not be able to respond since my accounts are being blocked in a few seconds after any posting but I should wait 20 min for the next post

---------- **Update1:**

Summons account was not closed, he was, I guess, pissed off by distortions of his question and deleting his answer.

It is good reason for mistreating my participation but not those whom I was answering

**Related questions:**

- [Why my account was closed in SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61200/why-my-account-was-closed-in-sf)
  -

Comment: "average of **450%** of **downvotes** " Ooh, that is a good reason!

Comment: "BTW, what is exactly the reason that I was suspended?" -- This was already answered in [your other post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61200/why-my-account-was-closed-in-sf) on the topic

Comment: I had an answer, but in looking at the revision history I'm rather baffled by what happened on that question. Does it look clearer for SF users who can see deleted posts? Is that what's missing from the view?

Answer (score 2):

Summon probably asked that his account be deleted.  Moderators don't generally delete accounts unless they are asked to by the account holder.

It might be worthwhile for you to read the FAQ, and lurk in ServerFault for awhile to get a feel for what is considered acceptable "protocol" for posting questions and answers.  It would be unfortunate if we lost a ServerFault user because he got frustrated by the chaotic nature of the interaction on his question.

Comment: Summon never existed on Server Fault. The question was migrated from Stack Overflow and the OP hasn't created/associated a SF account to "reclaim" it.

Comment: @ChrisF You need to get 10k on SF, not just so that you can have 10k across the entire trilogy, but so that you can see what activity is in the deletions there. If you look at the revision history for that question, it's clear that Summon had some measure of interaction (perhaps as a separate cookie account, since the SO account is unregistered).

Comment: I remember running across this question when it came up. I distinctly noticed that 'Summon' from SO was in the 'no account here' state, and there is a question in the deleted-questions list from a Summon that is still on SF (http://serverfault.com/users/51191/summon). Zypher asked Summon in a comment to that deleted answer to see if he could get his accounts associated.

Comment: @Grace - Oh. I keep forgetting I only get a limited view of SF. At my current rate it will take a while before I get 10K though ;)